# How do I show that: $\cos^2(z)+\sin^2(\bar{z})=1+\mathrm i\beta $ using series evaluation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, proof-verification

I'm sorry to ask this question:

let  $z$ be a complex variable and  $\bar{z}$ its conjugate. How do I show 
 that $$\cos^2(z)+\sin^2(\bar{z})=1+\mathrm i\beta$$ and $\beta$ is a real number with $\mathrm i$ the unit imaginary part .

**Note**: I would like to show it if it is true using series evaluation but it's hard and complicated to show it.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Use $\frac{1}{2} (2-\cos(2 x)+\cos(2 y)) = \sin^2(x)+\cos^2(y)$

Comment: If you insist on using the power series, compute the series for $\cos^2 w$ and $\sin^2 w$ e.g. like [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1542705), and note that the series expansion shows that $\sin^2 \overline{z} - \sin^2 z$ is purely imaginary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relation $\cos^2z+\sin^2z=1$ holds also for complex values of $z$, because the derivative is $0$ (that you can compute with the power series, of course).

Thus $\cos^2z+\sin^2\bar{z}=1-\sin^2z+\sin^2\bar{z}$ and you want to prove that
$$
(\sin z-\sin\bar{z})(\sin z+\sin\bar{z})
$$
is purely imaginary.
Now, from the power series for the sine, you get
$$
\sin z-\sin\bar{z}=
\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n+1}-\bar{z}^{2n+1}}{(2k+1)!}
$$
which is a sum of purely imaginary numbers, whereas
$$
\sin z+\sin\bar{z}=
\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n+1}+\bar{z}^{2n+1}}{(2k+1)!}
$$
is a sum of real numbers.

Alternatively, the power series expansion shows
$$
\sin\bar{z}=\overline{\sin z}
$$
and $w^2-\bar{w}^2$ is purely imaginary for every complex number $w$.

Comment: it is a nice answer ,thanks